# What permission level do you need in VSTS to create Test Plans

Tags: azure-devops

According to the Microsoft documentation, you need to have Basic access in VSTS in order to create Test Plans, however, when I log in with a user having Basic access, the link for adding a Test Plan is not there.

What additional access does this user need to be able to create Test Plans?  The user is also an administrator of the team to which Test Plans need to be added.

Screenshots showing the MS documentation, the particular user's access level, how it should look according to MS and how it does look (with the "+" icon to add Test Plans not appearing when logging in as the user in question with Basic access).

Comment: Did you install the Test Manager extension?

Comment: That does not appear to be what this MS article indicates.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/manual-test/manual-test-permissions.  It shows that a user with Contributor access should be able to Manage Test Plans and Test Suites (presumably without having to install the Test Manager extension).

Comment: Without the Test Manager extension, those capabilities aren't present **at all**. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That article introduce the testing permission and access, not for the way (UI) to manage test (e.g. Create test plan)

With basic access level and Contributors permission, you can create test plan. There are many ways to create test plan, such as **Microsoft Test Manager** (client software), [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/plans#create-a-testplan). But you can’t do it in Test tab without Test Manager extension, which is used to manage test online (test tab).

To conclude, if you want to create test plan on online (test tab), you need to install Test manager extension. You can build a custom extension to manage test through [calling REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/call-rest-api) in order to manage test online without install Test manager extension.

Answer (score 1):

The Test Manager module in VSTS requires additional license.
It costs $52 per month per user.
Also Visual Studio Enterprise subscription includes this license.

So, as you are using Basic license of VSTS the Test Manager module is not fully available, even with Administrator role.

Comment: That does not appear to be what this MS article indicates.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/manual-test/manual-test-permissions.  It shows that a user with Contributor access should be able to Manage Test Plans and Test Suites.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be explained at documentation.

I found this link [Test Plans](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/testmanagement/#exercise-1-managing-test-plans-suites-and-cases), I hope can be useful for anyone.

Once I clicked on Azure DevOps Portal at Test Plans, it shows this label.

> Upgrade to Test Manager extension to get full test management
>   capabilities Use the paid Test Manager extension to get access to
>   advanced test management capabilities like assign configurations,
>   assign testers, centralized parameters, authoring tests in grid view,
>   exporting test results etc. in your account. Learn more.

[Test plans view](https://aka.ms/testmanagerlearn)

Complementing with [Create a Test Plan.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-a-test-plan?view=vsts)